# can´t use get_post(), get_post_meta() and another functions

Tags: php, xml, wordpress, loops

i am having problem to use a get_post, get_post_meta, sanitize_text_field,
and any another function in php file to generate a XML code.
i Checked in all post here but i did not find nothing, so i need to ask.
the thing is i need to make a feed xml to export all custom posts from my database in wordpress, basically i just connect to the DB and get all information using ( mysql_query), this is the basic code that i use, by the wy, i used before but not in wordpress DB, was in Joomla DB:

CODE:

```
<?php header('Content-type: text/xml; charset="utf-8"', true);

// Set the database access information as constants:

$host = "any";
$dbuser = "any";
$pass = "any";
$database = "any";

$linkID = mysql_connect($host, $dbuser, $pass) or die("No se puede conectar     al servidor WEB");
mysql_select_db($database, $linkID) or die("No se puede encontrar la BD en el Servidor");
mysql_set_charset("utf8");

$query = sprintf( "SELECT ID, post_author as autor, post_title as titulo,     post_content as descripcion, post_name as urlamigable FROM database WHERE   post_status = '%s' AND post_type = '%s'", mysql_real_escape_string($post_status), mysql_real_escape_string($post_type) ); 

$resultID = mysql_query($query, $linkID) or die("NO se pudo ejecutar la consulta o no hay resultados que mostrar.");

echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n";
echo "<node>\n";
 echo $query;

// $homeland_price = sanitize_text_field( get_post_meta($row['ID'],     'post_meta_key', true ) );

for($x = 0 ; $x < mysql_num_rows($resultID) ; $x++)
{
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultID);
    echo "<node1>\n";

        echo "<ID>" .$row['ID']. "</ID>\n";
        echo "<autor>"  .$row['autor']. "</autor>\n";

// $titulo =    sanitize_text_field($row['titulo']);
// <![CDATA[$row['titulo']]]>  $titulo = esc_attr($row['titulo']);

        echo "<titulo>" .$row$['titulo']. "</titulo>\n";
        echo "<descripcion>" .$row$['descripcion']. "</descripcion>\n";

    echo "</node1>\n";
}
mysql_free_result($resultID);

 echo "</node>\n";  
 exit ();  
 ?>
```

in this case ID and AUTOR field are int numbers and there is no problem but TITULO and DESCRIPCION fields are Text Fields and i cant get the real value for that, even the same code that i used in joomla `<![CDATA[" . $row['titulo'] . "]]>`  not work and get error.
SO why that i tryed to use the funtions that comes with workpress to work with the posts, but when i tryed to use it allways come error like "Fatal error: Call to undefined function **sanitize_text_field()** in /public_html/feedxml.php on line 40"

I tried also to include the files where is this functions using "include" or "require" or "require_once" but not work too, even said the same error.

why that i don't know now what can i do to use this functions.

Comment: You need to run it inside wordpress, you should at least require wp-load.php

Comment: Hi Lanis, sorry for ask, what do you mean with "inside wordpress", i run the file for example in this direction (/home/my-account/public_html/feedxml.php), but even i change the directory many time for example to (/home/my-account/public_html/wp-includes/feedxml.php) and got the same error.

Comment: As well i tryed to include many file and directory as you comment before, like this,  "require_once( '../../wp-load.php' );"  or  including the full address like "include( '/home/my-account/public_html/wp-load.php' );", or including the directory using all combination and got the same error. This page contains the following errors:

error on line 2 at column 1: Extra content at the end of the document
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to include `wp-load.php` in that file you are working... like

```
require_once( '../../../wp-load.php' );
```

Comment: Hi Shafi, thanks for the answer, but i did it using require, require_once or include as you said, but nothing, got the same error, This page contains the following errors:

error on line 2 at column 1: Extra content at the end of the document
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error. Even i tryed to add the full directory for example /home/my-account/public_html/wp-includes/   but nothing, dont find the funtions that i tryed to use, dont understand.

Comment: are you using that inside a plugin?

Comment: No shafi, the full code is all that you see in the post, i use it runing from the url, for example, mydomain.com/feedxml.php and get a xml code with all resut información.

Comment: Yes of course, the code are in the original post, that's all i have, tell me if you need something else.                           See.  kolstadproperty.com/feedxml.php

Comment: can you please give me table name and fields here?

Comment: echo "<titulo>" .$row$['titulo']. "</titulo>\n";
        echo "<descripcion>" .$row$['descripcion']. "</descripcion>\n";  please remove $ after row- so change $row$['titulo'] to $row['titulo'] and check please. may be error is there

Comment: sorry was an error writing the code in the post but in the file is without this "$".  The name of the table is the posts table in wordpress, in my case is "kpa_posts" and the filds are "post_author as autor, post_title as titulo,     post_content as descripcion, post_name as urlamigable". Thanks

Comment: i wil try to recopde

Comment: thanks a lot for all, speccioally to Shafi, i just solve the problem including require_once(wp-load.php). thanks